# Prevent Entity Framework from Creating a Composite Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to prevent Entity Framework from creating a composite primary key on one of my tables.  I have the following two entities:

```
public class Entry
{
   public Int64 EntryID { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string EntrySubject { get; set; }
}

public class Revision
{
   public Int64 RevisionID { get; set; }
   public string RevisionDescription { get; set; }

   public Int64 EntryID { get; set; }
   public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}
```

When Entity Framework generates the database, the Revisions table gets a composite primary key made up of RevisionID and EntryID.  I would like the primary key for the Revisions table to be RevisionID only.  Is there a way to do that?  (I am using Entity Framework 4.3 with SQL Server CE, if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute.aspx) Data Annotation in your Revision class, to explicitly define your key:

```
public class Revision
{
   [Key]
   public Int64 RevisionID { get; set; }
   public string RevisionDescription { get; set; }

   public Int64 EntryID { get; set; }
   public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}
```

or using Fluent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Revision>().HasKey(r=>r.RevisionID)
```

EDIT: Added test app and diagram

I created a test app, with a Key annotation and it created the following database, with a primary key on Revisions table with only RevisionID

[image]

Entirety of the app:

```
namespace ExampleCF
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public Int64 EntryID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string EntrySubject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Revision
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 RevisionID { get; set; }
        public string RevisionDescription { get; set; }

        public Int64 EntryID { get; set; }
        public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entry> Entrys { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Revision> Revisions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }   

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried both of those methods but neither method worked.  I have a stripped down test application with just these two classes and I just confirmed that adding the Key annotation does not work.  I still get a composite key.

Comment: I created a test app (code posted) and did not get the same result - it created a table with the key as intended.  Can you post your test app?

Comment: Ah, I'm getting two different results.  When I use your code and just allow SqlExpress to create the database, I get the same results as you with no composite primary key.  But when I use SQL Server CE with your code and specify the CE database (.sdf) using a connection string setting, I get the composite key.  So the issue seems to be with SQL Server CE (I’m using the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact NuGet package, v4.3.5).  So I guess my question becomes, can this behavior be prevented when using CE.  But I’ll check your answer since it led met to the source of the problem.  Thank you.