# Remove composite primary key for the join table created by entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, composite-primary-key

I have two classes, Product and Invoice, with many to many relationship between them

Entity framework has created three tables for me, Products, Invoices, and a join table called, InvoiceProducts (or something like that)

As I have learned, by default, entity framework creates a composite primary key on the fields `InvoiceId` and `ProductId` in the join table, so together, those foreign keys, must be unique.

Well, this is an issue, cause sometimes a person wants to order two of the same item, in the same invoce.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380576/prevent-entity-framework-from-creating-a-composite-primary-key) answer, but it only helps if you are creating the join table in C# as well. But when using entity framework, I no longer create a join table, I just Create my classes as the following:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB() : base("MyConnectionstringName") { }

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

So, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default, convenient mapping for many-to-many tables where you just want to associate the two tables with one another. Something like what you describe could involve adding something like a "Quantity" to the InvoiceProducts table. (rather than duplicating the same ProductId+InvoiceId combination)

This would involve adding an InvoiceProduct entity:

```
public class InvoiceProduct
{
    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Invoice), Column(Order=0)]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; } 
    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Product), Column(Order=1)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

The navigation properties in your Invoice and Product entities need to be changed to InvoiceProducts rather than Products and Invoices respectively.  From there you can still access the respective collection, but it's a little less convenient because the collection will be typed to InvoiceProduct which allows you to get to the Quantity column for the relationship. For instance to list the Products for an invoice you would need to use `invoice.InvoiceProducts.Select(x => x.Product);` rather than `invoice.Products`.

The default many-to-many mapping is more convenient, but limited to just representing the relationship. Mapping the joining table entity gives you more flexibility for requirements like this.

Edit: The alternative is to replace the Many-to-Many with a One-to-Many-to-One relationship using a Joining table that has a dedicated PK column w9th the FKs to each table.

For instance:

```
public class InvoiceProduct
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InvoiceProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Invoice), Column(Order=0)]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Product), Column(Order=1)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Personally, I would prefer the Quantity column where the combination forms the PK. Using this approach looking through the data honestly looks like a bug. When you look at something like an invoice that lists products, these are typically presented as a Product, a price, a quantity, and a total. If I order 10 instances of the same product, I expect to see the product with a Qty of 10 and a total rather than 10 line items for the same product.  There is nothing architecturally wrong from a data schema or EF implementation using a Quantity field. The same approach is needed if you want to use something like a Soft-delete associations when removing product-invoice associations. (I.e. an IsActive rather than deleting the joining row) This would require defining an InvoiceProduct entity with the IsActive flag in the same way. (Same for tracking things like CreatedBy/Date, ModifiedBy/Date, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but is there a way to remove the unique index that is created by EF? my friend told me SSMS has a feature that makes tables neglect configurations like this, have you heard of anything like that?

Comment: Because, there's gotta be a better way. adding a quantity column seems architecturally wrong to me, doesn't it to you?

Comment: I have updated the example with an alternative using a unique Key for the joining entity. This would allow for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> adding a quantity column seems architecturally wrong to me, doesn't it to you?

No, but it's your data model.  If you want that then the model would be something like

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; } 
    public int InvoiceLineId { get; set; } 

    public int ProductId{ get; set; } 

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

Configured like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
        .HasMany(i => i.Products)
        .WithMany(p => p.Invoices)
        .UsingEntity<InvoiceLine>(
          e => e.HasOne( il => il.Product)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(il => il.ProductId),
          e => e.HasOne(il => il.Invoice)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(il => il.InvoiceId),
          e => e.HasKey(e => new { e.InvoiceId, e.InvoiceLineId })
        );


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Note how you still have a Many-to-Many and don't have to directly deal with the InvoiceLine entities.  And it creates the table like

```
  CREATE TABLE [InvoiceLine] (
      [InvoiceId] int NOT NULL,
      [InvoiceLineId] int NOT NULL,
      [ProductId] int NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceLine] PRIMARY KEY ([InvoiceId], [InvoiceLineId]),
      CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceLine_Invoice_InvoiceId] FOREIGN KEY ([InvoiceId]) REFERENCES [Invoice] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceLine_Product_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [Product] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );


  CREATE INDEX [IX_InvoiceLine_ProductId] ON [InvoiceLine] ([ProductId]);
```